# How to bind event to elements with specific class in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

What is the proper way to listen the click event on elements with class "foo"?

```
<div>
    <p class="foo">Hi</p>
    <span class="foo">Hello</span>
    <p class="bar">Hey</p>
<div>
<div class="foo">
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

I think this version is a bit fragile:

```
<div>
    <p class="foo" (click)="bar()">Hi</p>
    <span class="foo" (click)="bar()">Hello</span>
    <p class="bar">Hey</p>
<div>
<div class="foo" (click)="bar()">
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the template or part of the template:

```
<div>
    <p class="foo">Hi</p>
    <span class="foo">Hello</span>
    <p class="bar">Hey</p>
<div>
<div class="foo">
    <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

You can create a `@Directive()` for it and bind the event to the `host` property:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector : '.bar', // <---selects only .bar elements
    host:{
      "(click)":"bar()"
    }
})

export class BarDirective{

    bar(){
       console.log('clicked');
    }

}
```

There are other decorators also like `@HostListener()`, but it has to be imported from `@angular/core` and bind the event within the class block instead.

Comment: Thank you!
Is it possible to handle this event in its own component.ts? It would modify some variables. Or should I implement a service for the communication between the new directive and the component?